# using wcf service to download a file from server

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a winform application that my clients uses.
When an update is available I notify them and they download it.
Now, my goal is to know which of my clients downloaded the update and when.
I was unclear how to manage that and read something about WCF service that may help me acomplish that. 
So my questions are:

1. Is wcf the right way to go ?
2. I purchased a static ip address and assigned it to my server. Whats next?
3. If this is the way to go, I would like to enable my clients to download the update file from my server. today I am using an outside storage utilities such as dropbox. is that possible ?

Any help and clarification would be great.

Comment: I think its better to use ClickOnce for deployement and update application.

Comment: I don't want to use clickOnce. Can it be done with wcf ?

Comment: You can do anything programmatically with WCF, but if you need application updates, I think the right way is using ClickOnce.

Comment: What's your limitations and why you can't use ClickOnce?

Answer (score 0):

While WCF *can* be used for many things, including this, in my experience it is great when used for SOAP web services. In almost every other case it is over-complicated. I think it would just add complexity in your case.

As commented by @Reza Aghaei, ClickOnce could be a good solution for you. For security reasons ClickOnce applications have some restrictions on what they can do at run-time though. Also, when using ClickOnce you would preferably sign your application using an AuthentiCode certificate.These are relatively expensive, which might also cause you a problem.

If these kinds of restrictions do not apply to you though, ClickOnce works really well and is very simple for you and your users. Much simpler than WCF.

If you can't use ClickOnce for one of the above reasons, or some other reason, and you just want to download an update file, the simplest way could be to use FTP.This would be a lot simpler than WCF in my opinion:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your applications can be Full Trust and this way they have no restrictions.

Comment: True, but the user has to explicitly give permissions for that so it make it two clicks instead of one ;o) Also, I think it's the case that in some corporate environments, this could be prevented by Group Policy. Don't get me wrong - if it can work, I think ClickOnce should be the preferred solution.